# how to send goal value dynamically from website to google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

i am unable to send google analytics goal value from my destination page to google analytics help me how i can send dynamic goal value from my site

here is my code to send dynamic goal value

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m) 
{i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o) 
[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
 })(window,document,'script','//www.google- 
 analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'XXXXXXX(id here)', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', '2');


  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Google Tag Manager. You'll be able to set up the events as below, using a variable to populate the dynamic value (this could be the value of a javascript variable, an element of the page, etc

[Create a new tag for Universal Google Analytics and select Track Type 'Event'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx3Ml.jpg)